# Developing in Qt for iOS on windows

Tags: windows, qt, ipad

Is it possible to develop some application on windows with Qt and use that to create application for iOs/IPad?

Answer (score 1):

Qt applications are mostly portable, in most cases the same code will run on any platform that Qt supports, as long as it doesn't use any platform specific APIs.

You cannot create Qt application executables for macos or ios without a macos machine, but you can develop your application on a windows machine, then simply compile the written code on a macos machine and you are set.